# Union of sorted sized queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have docs in `Elasticsearch` like:

```
{
    "key1":1,
    "key2":2,
    "key3":3
}
```

I would like to make a query that returns 30 docs which are the union of the:

- the 10 docs with the highest values in `key1` +
- the 10 docs with the highest values in `key2` +
- the 10 docs with the highest values in `key3`

I got 2 ideas:

1. Using `DisMaxQuery` - but I couldn't use sorting. Probably missed something..
2. using `MultiSearch` - but I would like to get one result object

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to add three `terms` aggregations on `key1`, `key2` and `key3` each sorted by a `max` sub-aggregation (in order to get the highest value for each key) and for each of them you can add a another `top_hits` sub-aggregation. You might get more less than 10 docs per key, if that's a problem you can increase the `size` of the `terms` aggregations to 2 or 3 and then filter out the unneeded top hits on the client side.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "topkey1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key1",
        "size": 1,
        "order": {
          "max_key1": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_key1": {
          "max": {
            "field": "key1"
          }
        },
        "key1_tophits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "topkey2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key2",
        "size": 1,
        "order": {
          "max_key2": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_key2": {
          "max": {
            "field": "key2"
          }
        },
        "key2_tophits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "topkey3": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key3",
        "size": 1,
        "order": {
          "max_key3": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_key3": {
          "max": {
            "field": "key3"
          }
        },
        "key_tophits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is also a nice approach but its not what im looking for as well.
i need to find a way to add sorting and size to `DisMaxQuery`